# Mcomp rolling forecasts with re-estimation

Tags: forecasting

I'm looking to run rolling one-step ahead forecasts on the Mcomp holdout data (future data), with re-estimation at each point, i.e. re-estimation over the entire historical and already forecast holdout data. As Mcomp is partitioned into historical (x) data and future (xx) data, I am unsure of how to step through to achieve this. My current h=1 incarnation follows, with thanks to Stephan Kolassa:

```
library(forecast)
library(Mcomp)

result <- structure(rep(NA,length(M3)),.Names=names(M3)) 
pb <- winProgressBar(max=length(M3)) 
for ( ii in seq_along(M3) ) { 
setWinProgressBar(pb,ii,paste(ii,"of " ,length(M3))) 
yy <- M3[[ii]] 
naive.model <- fitted(arima(yy$x, order=c(0,1,0)))
arima.model <- auto.arima(yy$x)
arima.forecast <- forecast(arima.model,h=1)$mean
a<-mean(abs(naive.model-yy$x))
b<-mean(abs(arima.forecast-yy$xx[1]))
result[ii] <- b/a
} 
close(pb) 
result 
write.csv(result, file = "arima.csv")
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out whether this is a statistical question or a purely programming/software question. If it's the latter, the question would be better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stepping though is not the problem. My question is what you want `a` to do while you are rolling your forecasts. Right now, `a` is the MAE over the entire holdout sample, but if you do rolling forecasts, `a` would be based on fewer and fewer holdout observations. Is that what you want?

Comment: The code above has "a" as the in-sample MAE of the naïve forecast. For the rolling I will change this to MASE. Thanks

Comment: @StephanKolassa Congrats on reaching 10k ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One point to keep in mind is that M3 has/had series of different periodicities and different holdout lengths.

```
> table(sapply(M3,"[[","period"),sapply(M3,"[[","h"))

               6    8   18
  MONTHLY      0    0 1428
  OTHER        0  174    0
  QUARTERLY    0  756    0
  YEARLY     645    0    0
```

As you see, the 1428 MONTHLY series all have 18 holdout periods, the 756 QUARTERLY and the 174 OTHER ones 8 periods and the 645 YEARLY series have 6 holdout periods. So you can either create one 1428x18 matrix for the 18 one-step-ahead forecasts for MONTHLY series, another matrix for OTHER, etc. - or you can simply create one big `list()`, with one entry (of varying length) for each M3 series. Let's do the second approach.

Create a `list` to hold the results, and set up a progress bar (on Windows):

```
result <- list()
pb <- winProgressBar(max=length(M3))
```

Step through the entries of `M3`:

```
for ( ii in seq_along(M3) ) {
```

Update the progress bar:

```
    setWinProgressBar(pb,ii,paste(ii,"of " ,length(M3)))
```

Prepare the current entry of `results` (indexed by the name of the `ii`th entry of `M3`) by setting it to an empty `ts` with the same `start`, `end` and `frequency` as the original holdout sample:

```
    result[[names(M3)[ii]]] <- ts(start=start(M3[[ii]]$xx),
          end=end(M3[[ii]]$xx),frequency=frequency(M3[[ii]]$xx))
```

Collect the original in-sample and out-of-sample observations in one big vector:

```
    yy <- c(M3[[ii]]$x,M3[[ii]]$xx)
```

Step through the possible rolling origins:

```
    for ( hh in 1:M3[[ii]]$h ) {
```

Define the history, by using the appropriate initial segment of `yy` and turning it into a `ts` object with the right `start` and `frequency`:

```
        yy.history <- ts(yy[1:(length(M3[[ii]]$x)+hh-1)],
              start=start(M3[[ii]]$x),frequency=frequency(M3[[ii]]$x))
```

Fit an `auto.arima` model based on this history. Forecast out to the end of the total sample (note that this will of course be of different lengths for different origins!) and take the point (`mean`) forecast:

```
        arima.forecast <- forecast(auto.arima(yy.history),
          h=length(yy)-length(yy.history))$mean
```

Take the mean absolute error of this forecast by comparing it to the current holdout:

```
        b <- mean(abs(arima.forecast-yy[-seq_along(yy.history)]))
```

For the denominator of the MASE, take the in-sample mean absolute error of the naive random walk forecast:

```
        a <- mean(abs(yy.history[-1]-head(yy.history,-1)))
```

Finally, write the MASE `b/a` into the correct entry of the current `result` slot:

```
        result[[names(M3)[ii]]][hh] <- b/a
    }   
} 
close(pb)
```

Now, you will of course not be able to write `result` to a csv file, since (as per above) `result` is a `list`, where each entry is a vector (actually a `ts` object) *of different length*. However, you could subset `result` using `sapply(M3,"[[","period")` or some such and then do separate analyses by different frequencies.